# How is scoring calculated in Tilt to Live?

Tags: tilt-to-live

In the game Tilt To Live for Iphone, you get points for killing red dots. If you can kill several of them in a short period of time, you can build combos that quickly increase your score.

As far as I can tell, each time you complete a combo, two numbers are multiplied to calculate your score. What do these 2 numbers mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You receive a certain amount of score for killing a red dot or collecting a powerup.  This value increases by differing amounts depending on whether or not you killed a dot, or collected a powerup, and is the first number in the set.  Of note is the fact that different power ups give you different scores.

The second number is the score multiplier, and increases by 1 every time you do either, within the time-out limit of the combo.

Therefore, in the example below:

**[ COMBO 48 x 3 ]**

'48' is the base score you have received from your heroic actions over the course of that particular multiplier, but *before* multiplication.  The '3' represents your current multiplier.  If you fail to continue the combo in a short enough amount of time, that is what your current combo score (48) will be multiplied by, and the combo ended.

Comment: I'm unconvinced it's purely a time limit thing. While trying for the achievements for using only the original four weapons, I noticed that my combo seemed to be getting much higher with much longer delays between kills than usual. This leads me to suspect it might also be tied in with accuracy.

Comment: @Zxaos > This is worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the first number is always 6 times greater than the second.

6d x d = combo score

d = # of dots killed in a time period

Example: you kill 15 dots in a time period

6d x d

6(15) x 15

90 x 15

1350 pts

Killing a dot = 10 pts
Using a weapon = 10 pts